# spring-cloud-starter-config file on Github not read

Tags: spring, cloud, config

Config on Spring-cloud-config
Spring doen't read mt repository Github

HI,
i use spring boot 3.2.1.
I want put my config on Github.

Here my configuration :

File Springboot

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.jwtapi", "com.jwtapi.common" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.jwtapi.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.jwtapi.repository" })
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class JwtApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JwtApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

File application.properties :

```
spring.application.name=JwtApi

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/<nom>/config-repo
```

Add File pom.xml

```
spring-cloud.version -> 2023.0.0
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

But it doesn't work. And i don't see Zero attempts to read my repository on Github.

Help me!!

Comment: i have not this logINFO 12345 --- [main] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: file:/path/to/local/config/application.properties
INFO 12345 --- [main] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: classpath:/application.properties
INFO 12345 --- [main] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Fetching config from server at : http://config-server:8888
INFO 12345 --- [main] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Located environment: name=application, profiles=[dev], label=null, version=null